# Access to API using Redux

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I have a react-redux app. I need to call API and used it in my component. The app is called with fetch in function in utills.
All functions are group and export like this:

```
export const sportTeam = {
  getBasketballTeam,
  getBasketballTeamById,
}
function   getBasketballTeam() {
   let token = store.getState().UserReducer.token;
fetch(
    actions.GET_BASKETBALLTEAM,
{
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    }
  )
    .then((res) => {
      if (res.status == 200 ) {
        return res.json();
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

getBasketballTeam contains an array of objects.
How can I get getBasketballTeam and used it in the component in the view to returning the list with this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want your `getBasketballTeam` function to access the store directly through `store.getState()`.

What you want is a "thunk" action creator that gets the store instance as an argument when you `dispatch` it.

The flow that you want is this:

0. Component continuously listens to the basketball team state with `useSelector` (or `connect`).
1. Component mounts.
2. Component dispatches a `getBasketballTeam` action.
3. Action fetches data from the API.
4. Reducer saves data from the action to the state.
5. State updates.
6. Component re-renders with the new data from state.

---

The easiest way to do this is with the [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) function from Redux Toolkit.  This helper handles all errors by dispatching a separate error action.  Try something like this:

Action:

```
export const fetchBasketballTeam = createAsyncThunk(
  "team/fetchBasketballTeam",
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().user.token;
    if ( ! token ) {
      throw new Error("Missing access token.");
    }
    const res = await fetch(actions.GET_BASKETBALLTEAM, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
    });
    if (res.status !== 200) {
      throw new Error("Invalid response");
    }
    // what you return is the payload of the fulfilled action
    return res.json();
  }
);
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  status: "idle",
  data: null
};

export const teamReducer = createReducer(initialState, (builder) =>
  builder
    .addCase(fetchBasketballTeam.pending, (state) => {
      state.status = "pending";
    })
    .addCase(fetchBasketballTeam.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "fulfilled";
      delete state.error;
      state.data = action.payload;
    })
    .addCase(fetchBasketballTeam.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "rejected";
      state.error = action.error;
    })
);
```

Store:

```
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    team: teamReducer,
    user: userReducer,
  }
});
```

Component:

```
export const BasketballTeam = () => {
  const { data, error, status } = useSelector((state) => state.team);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      dispatch(fetchBasketballTeam());
    },
    // run once on mount
    // or better: take the token as an argument and re-run if token changes
    [dispatch]
  );

  if (status === "pending") {
    return <SomeLoadingComponent />;
  }

  if (!data) {
    return <SomeErrorComponent />;
  }

  // if we are here then we definitely have data
  return <div>{/* do something with data */}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get response you need to do the following things

1. call dispatch function to store the data received in REDUX state.
2. Now when you have data in redux state, you can use useSelector() to get that state and make use of it in your jsx file.